# Sharepoint 2007: SSRS viewer: How to show/hide web part on condition

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise

I have few SSRS reports that I want to show to the user. But not all of them are to be showed to all users. Depending upon some attribute of the user, I need to hide/show few of the reports [or the webpart].

I want to avoid to carry all these filtering to inside the report.

I just saw SharePoint Web Part Visibility Filter Web Part on http://spvisibilityfilter.codeplex.com/. Is there any other simpler and out-of-the box capability in Sharepoint 2007 that I may use?

Answer (score 1):

You could put audience targetting on the web part properties. This would hide them from people not defined in the web part.

Comment: Thanks. But audience targettinng allows one to set it to certain group or users. What I was looking at is to set it to users having certain value in one of its attributes. Can I use audience targetting for this scenario?

Comment: You could probably use the User Filter web part since you're on enterprise. Configure it and your SSRS view(s) so that they're pushing the correct user attribute from the filter web part to the connected SSRS web part. That should then trim the reports out that aren't applicable.

Comment: Is there a User Filter available on Sharepoint 2007/MSPS 2005? I could not see it.

Comment: Make sure the Enterprise features are enabled in Site Settings and when you go to add a web part to your page, it should appear in the Filters section. It might be called Current User Filter.